# Confuse after quickstart

Tags: google-drive-api

I am pretty new to Google Drive SDk. After spend hours on the google drive sdk document and quick start app, I think I have known some basic concepts about it. 
However, I have a easy but crucial question: how to integrate my code with Drive UI. 
I mean I know I should enable Google Drive API and Google Drive SDK and do some configure staff. And I did.

I set up the MIME type that my app should be able to open and create, but it doesn't work. (I used the most easy one: plain/text: txt).

In fact, I think this is not the most serious problem. I am confused about how to integrate my code with Drive UI.
I mean the quick start app works fine, but it just simply upload a file. What if I want to perform some complicate action after user open a certain file with my app?

Ideally, I think it should redirect the user to my open URL and all the actions should go with that site, right?
(I am using Python, in case that could make any differences)

I am really confused. Excuse my chaos description, please.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Thanks for the answering below! I think I need to detailed explain my needs from google drive sdk.

Basically, I want the user who have installed my app be able to open a certain file (which should be spreadsheet or txt) on google drive. Then it will redirect the user to my given Open URL (which I create a site by using google site). On that site, user should be able to view and import the content of file into a certain database. None of the operations above require any technique knowledges. I certainly can do this by writing python script and run it locally to import the content of files on google drive. However, there are two issues: first, I need to run it locally. I mean I did use the google drive api, but I didn't explore the real benefit of api; second, it is still a command line script, and has to be ran on linux.

I hope I have illustrated my request. And I appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: Don't worry, what do you want to do with your app?

Comment: basically, I want the user to import the content of a certain file into a database by opening it (or maybe give a particular option: 'import'). Right now, I manually download the files from google drive to local machine and do the importing, I want to get rid of that manual download step. Thanks for any help!

Comment: By the way, do I need google app engine to implement my app?

Comment: @FanyongMeng, no you don't have to. But, our Python client also works fine on App Engine's Python runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the client library:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Acquire an access token as explained on the [Python Quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-python#step_3_set_up_the_sample). Init a Drive service to be able to talk to the API and authorize http transporter with your credentials. You need to make requests to get file metadata and file contents.

Retrieve file metadata:

```
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
f = drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()
```

Retrieve file contents:

```
downloadUrl = f.get('downloadUrl')
f['content'] = drive_service._http.request(downloadUrl)
```

(Don't forget content retrieving request should be authorized and authenticated, that's why we use drive_service._http to make that request.

Comment: thanks for answering! But I have known about you mentioned above. I even write a script to import the files. However, I need to use command line to do this. Ideally, I want someone who doesn't know linux or python be able to import the file. I mean he can open files fon google drive and import the content all by clicking. I will update my question to explain what I want.

Comment: @FanyongMeng, I dont totally understand the flow you want to implement. But, as far as I get, you want to "Open With..." your application from Drive UI and retrieve the contents of a set of files on your application. As an app provider, the actions you can perform are create and open. Please, take a look at https://developers.google.com/drive/integrate-open for details about opening. Waiting for you to update the question.

Comment: so the opening and creating are the only thing I can do with the google drive sdk? Then what is the point for opening it if you cannot perform any additional operations? I mean if you just wanna open a file, you guys have already provide the build-in apps to open and create the files with basically all the types, right?

Comment: @FanyongMeng, no, you're not just limited to creating and opening :) But if you want to perform a task from Google Drive frontend (drive.google.com), these are only actions you can perform. If you build a standalone app, you're free to implement anything you want to.

Comment: So as mentioned in your documents, after user open the file with my app on google drive front end, it should redirect the user to another page. And I should implement all my operations inside that new site, right? Is this what you say "standalone" app? Is that mean I should need google app engine to achieve this goal?

Comment: @FanyongMeng, yes, you can implement anything you need on your side. And no, you dont need Google App Engine. You can host your application anywhere you like to do. OAuth2 credentials will take care of the auth.

Comment: @FanyongMeng, on the other hand, why arent you listing files and directories on your application. You dont need Google Drive UI at all.

Comment: Well, I know I may host my app in another place, but google app engine is still a option, right? (or not? please clarify this, please.) The reason I want google app engine because I think it will take care a lot server side maintain work for me. And it is just a simple app, I won't take much time on set the server.

Comment: For your concern about why I have to stick on Google Drive, because my candidate users are using google drive to manage the files they are working on. I mean it is certainly doable to use your approach, but I have to convince them to switch to my new app to document and manage files, which is basically impossible. And you have to admit that google drive is good place for teams to document and manage files. Thanks for your advice and help, really.

Comment: @FanyongMeng, Google App Engine is still an option and our client libraries are working on App Engine too. You have a valid point and a  good reason, I'll talk to team to see if there is anything we can do in the future to address that.